# The explicit monoid law on the differences of two square integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, integers, square-numbers, monoid

It is known that if $S = \{ x^2 : x \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is the submonoid, then $\Delta S = \{ x^2 - y^2 : x,y\in \Bbb{Z}\}$ or the set of all differences of squares forms the monoid $4\Bbb{Z} \uplus( 2\Bbb{Z} + 1)$.

I was wondering, can you take two $a^2 - b^2, c^2 - d^2$ and come up with a formula for $x,y$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$ such that $(a^2 - b^2)(c^2 - d^2) = x^2 - y^2$?

Comment: Cf. [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity) with $n = -1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$ is a famous identity. Now substitute $b=ib’,d=id’$ to obtain $$(a^2-b^2)(c^2-d^2)=(ac-bd)^2-(ad-bc)^2$$.

Comment: I also found that $(ac + bd)^2 - (ad + bc)^2$ works.  So we're sure that both ways work?

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack Yeah. I'm not sure what a monoid is but you can think of it as two groups with the same set of elements but different group operation.

Comment: A monoid is the same thing as a group except it may not have inverses for some element.  So every group is a monoid.  You get to a  more general class of things by deleting axioms.  The axiom deleted here is invertibilty of every element.

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack Ah, I probably came across it when dealing with rings, where $(R \setminus \{0\}, \times)$ is a monoid

Comment: It's still a monoid when you include zero, but zero will be an all-absorbing element.  Still though $0\cdot 1 = 0$ so it works.